# XOR in C++ with big number

Tags: c++, c, cryptography

I want to use XOR for two big numbers in C++ . I use Miracl library for big numbers . how can I do it ?
for example:

```
X= 188DA80EB03090F67CBF20EB43A18800F4FF0AFD82FF1012
XOR
Y= 000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001
```

then shift the second number one bit and do this step again .I can't use X^Y. What should I do ?

another problem is with shift.
this is my code for shift :

[image]:

but instead of shift one bit to the left , it shifts 4 bit. this is the output :

[image]

please help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are referring to [this Miracl](https://github.com/CertiVox/MIRACL/blob/master/include/big.h), they mention a function called `lxor`:

```
friend Big lxor(const Big&,const Big&);   // logical XOR
```

Comment: For those like me who were worried about the comment, the core implementation of `mr_xor` in [mrcore.c](https://github.com/CertiVox/MIRACL/blob/master/source/mrcore.c) shows that the operation is performed bitwise.

Comment: @ChrisCulter Good to know, thanks for researching it!

Comment: @cnicutar thanks . But I couldn't use this function . also I couldn't find it in miracl help !

Comment: @ChrisCulter : I get it . thanks :) 
I just write :
mr_xor(X1,fault,X1)
that's very easy :P
but it's not in mrcore.c .I just saw mr_and in this file!